# Why do we need to specify partition type in fdisk and later again in mkfs?

Tags: filesystems, partition, fdisk

I'm a little confused about **fdisk** and **mkfs**.

So - here is typical USB flash drive partitioning and formatting:

```
umount /dev/sdb
fdisk fdisk /dev/sdb

Command (m for help): d
Selected partition 1

Command (m for help): n
Command action
e   extended
p   primary partition (1-4)
p
Partition number (1-4): 1
First cylinder (1-960, default 1): ↵
Using default value 1
Last cylinder or +size or +sizeM or +sizeK (1-960, default 960): ↵
Using default value 960 

Command (m for help): t
Selected partition 1
Hex code (type L to list codes): 6
Changed system type of partition 1 to 6 (FAT16)

Command (m for help): a
Partition number (1-4): 1

Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered!

Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.

WARNING: If you have created or modified any DOS 6.x 
partitions, please see the fdisk manual page for additional
information.

mkfs -t vfat /dev/sdb1
```

My question is:

Why do we even have to use **t** option to specify partition type while doing **fdisk** step?  How does it affect everything?  Does it create some mark on usb drive meaning that there only supposed to be vfat partition?
Or is it safe to skip **t** step altogether?
AFAIK - partitioning is only splitting disk into areas - is it not?

Just trying to understand why it works the way it works:)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because mkfs does not know or care about partition tables.  You can use it on any block device you wish, including those that have nothing to do with a hard disk, and therefore partitions.  The partition type code that fdisk puts in the msdos partition table is only a hint and is pretty much ignored by non Microsoft operating systems.

Answer (score 6):

The partition type is less specific than the filesystem type. Most "native" Linux filesystems use partition type 83, for example: all of the `ext*` variants, ReiserFS, XFS, and others.

You should try switching to [`parted`](https://www.gnu.org/s/parted/) or `gParted`. For some filesystem types, it is able to create the partition and create a filesystem in it all within the same tool. (With some filesystems, you still have to `mkfs` separately, though.)

Answer (score 5):

The partition type is for devices that need to know what type of filesystem you are putting on that partition. Linux seems to be clever enough to just ignore the type, and knows what the filesystem is no matter what. However, there are some devices that will only be able to read your disk if the filesystem type matches the actual filesystem that you put on the disk.

`mkfs` creates the actual filesystem. It doesn't know what sort of thing you are putting that filesystem on, so it can't just guess. You need to tell it exactly what sort of filesystem you are trying to create so that it knows what to do.

I found out recently why it matters what the filesystem type is. I setup a usb stick for putting songs on to use in a media player, however I didn't set the filesystem type correctly, even though the actual filesystem was vfat. The music player had no idea how to read the drive, it worked once the partition type was set correctly. I also had the same problem on a mac, a usb stick with the wrong partition type couldn't be read even though the actual filesystem was fine.